# How can I get the date data by clicking the button using datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Click the button to display the data within a month. What should I do?

in this html code

```
 <input type="text" id='start' class="form-control datepicker"> 
 <input type="text" id='end' class="form-control datepicker"> 

<button class="btn" type="button" id="btn_search"></button>
```

in this javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Datapicker 
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
          "dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd"
      });
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so, flag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Datapicker - created on document.ready
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  "dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd"
});

function getDates() {
  const $start = $('#start');
  const $end = $('#end');
  let dateStart = $start.datepicker('getDate'); // js Date() object
  let dateEnd = $end.datepicker('getDate'); // js Date() object
  let dateStartFormatted = $start.val(); // string
  let dateEndFormatted = $end.val(); // string
  console.log('Start:', dateStartFormatted, dateStart);
  console.log('End:', dateEndFormatted, dateEnd);
}
```

```html
<!-- this is just adding libraries: -->
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- this is your code: -->
<input type="text" id='start' class="form-control datepicker">
<input type="text" id='end' class="form-control datepicker">

<button class="btn" type="button" id="btn_search" onclick="getDates()">Press me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of bootstrap, use format: "yy-mm-dd" instead of dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yy/mm/dd"
      });
    });

    function search() {
      $(".text").html("Selected date value between " + $('#start').val() + " and " + $('#end').val());
    }
```

```css
.btn{
      background-color:grey;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 form-control datepicker" id="start">
     
      <input type="text"  class="col-sm-2 form-control datepicker" id="end">

      <button class="btn" type="button" id="btn_search" onclick=search()>Search</button>
      </div>
      <span class="text"></span>
    </div>
```